# How to prevent google analytics from getting traffic from localhost?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have an issue.
I use google analytics in a small project, and I develop on localhost. Of course I call my site again and again on my local machine, but this pullutes my analytics stats.
What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats quit simple.

1. you have the possibility to filter it in analytics, but this option
   jungle in analytics is a bit confusing in my opinion.
2. you can just do it in your javascript:

   ```
   if (window.location.hostname != 'localhost' && window.location.hostname != '127.0.0.1') {
       //put your analytics here    
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hard-coding your google analytics key inside the rendered HTML, I suggest to put it in a configuration file.

It's typical to have several config files - at least one for the production app and one for a developer setup. Then in the developer settings you can disable GA altogether or just put a different key (for a testing site, so that you can e.g. check if your event tracking works properly).

Another option is to use the [Google Analytics debug version](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/debugging) and disabling the network part, so that you can preview the hits in console without actually registering them:

```
ga('set', 'sendHitTask', null);
```

---

I'd rather avoid checking for `localhost` host in Javascript. What if another developer uses `localhost:8000`? What if you deploy to a staging server? Config files are more reliable and flexible.